# Asymptotic normality of estimator and change of sign

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Say that given an estimator $\hat{T}$, of a statistic $T$, we have that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \overset{{\strut\text{D}}}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,Var)$, where $n$ is the sample size. Consider now $-\hat{T}$, does the asymptotic result hold also in this case? If yes/no, under which conditions?

EDIT: more information to make te problem clear. Say that we are interested in the following statistic

\begin{equation}
     S=
          \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
           1-T &\text{if}\quad  x \geq 1/2 \\
           T-1 &\text{if} \quad  x< 1/2
        \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}.

We also know that when $x \neq 1/2$, $\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \overset{{\strut\text{D}}}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,Var)$. Can we say the same for $S$ and $\hat{S}$? The hat denotes the estimator, all the considered statistics depend only on $x$.

Comment: I feel like you are misusing the word "statistic." Is $T$ an unknown [non-random] parameter of a distribution, or is it really a function of the sample?

Comment: Definetly I misused, $T$ is an unknown population parameter (in my case a coefficient), same for S, whereas $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{S}$ are estimators computed on observed data.

Comment: Since $S$ is a population parameter that depends on $x$, does this mean $x$ is some other non-random population parameter?

Comment: In my case x is a probability of success from a Bernoulli. This probability is estimated in the sample using the relative frequencies.

Comment: Then you can just take $x$ to be fixed. Then $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S} - S) \to N(0, \text{Var})$.

Comment: I would proceed like this. When $x<1/2$ then we have $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S} - S)= \sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-1-T+1 )= \sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T)$ then the result immediately follows. In the case of $x> 1/2$ we would have  $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S} - S) = \sqrt{n}(-(\hat{T}-T))$, then what theorem should I use to say that the result still holds?

Comment: See what I stated in my answer below.

Comment: I cannot understand why should I use convergence in distribution and Slutsky. My solution, I can use the fact that if $X\sim N(a,b)$, then $cX \sim \mathcal{N}(ca,c^2 b)$, so in the case $x< 1/2$ $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S} - S) = -\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \sim \mathcal{N}(-1*0,(-1)^2* Var)$, which gives the result. What do you think of my solution?

Comment: *In the case $x > 1/2$.

Comment: Yes you have the right idea regarding $X \sim N(0,V) \implies -X \sim N(0, V)$, but you cannot use $\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \sim N(0, V)$ since this is not assumed; the assumption in your question is $\sqrt{n}(\hat{T} - T) \overset{D}{\to} N(0, V)$. This implies $-\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \overset{D}{\to} N(0, V)$ as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I still do not get the property/theorem/proposition used to conclude that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{T} - T) \overset{D}{\to} N(0, V) \implies -\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \overset{D}{\to} N(0, V)$. Does $X \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(a,b)$, implies $cX \overset{D}{\to}  \mathcal{N}(ca,c^2 b)$? ($c$ is a constant). If yes, I'm done, I've understand everything. Sorry if I insist on this point, but I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: You should convince yourself of this claim by proving it yourself. One way is to look at how the CDFs of $X$ and $cX$ behave as $n \to \infty$ (definition of convergence in distribution), which is what I was suggesting in my answer.

Comment: By definition of convergence in distribution $P(\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \leq x)\to P(Y\le x)$, where $Y  \sim N(0, V)$, as $n \to \infty$. Also, we have that  $P(-\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \leq -x)\to P(-Y\leq -x)$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $-\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T) \overset{D}{\to}  \mathcal{N}(0,Var)$ because $-Y  \sim \mathcal{N}(-1*0,(-1)^2* Var)$. Then by noting that when $x>1/2$ I have $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S} - S) = -\sqrt{n}(\hat{T}-T)$ gives the result. Does it look good?

Comment: The definition of convergence in distribution has some technicality about convergence only at points of continuity of the target CDF that you did not mention, but otherwise this looks fine.

Comment: Would you like to state this technical condition that I omitted? Anyways, I've already selected your answer as the solution, if you want to add this I think it is useful for me and future readers. Thank you again.

Comment: $X_n \overset{D}{\to} X$ if $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ for each $x$ at which $F_X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_n \overset{D}{\to} X$ then $-X_n \overset{D}{\to} -X$. I think you can prove this directly using one of the many equivalent definitions of convergence in distribution, or use a hammer like [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Thus $\sqrt{n}((-\hat{T}) - (-T)) \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, V)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, before I answer to your comment, I've added an edit to provide more background on my question. I think that your rationale still applies, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: What does "we know that asymptotic normality holds when $\hat{T} \ge 0$" mean? Do you mean $\hat{T}_n \ge 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: I've written the question too messy, sorry for that. Now I've stated clearly the problem without omitting parts, hope that now is clear.